# How to check values properly before doing memmove()?

Tags: c

I'm using memmove and sometimes get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS. I want to precheck the ingoing values to prevent this error.

Its from an opensource c project that’s not supported anymore.
I can build and run it and it works great, but I don't know how to change the C code to make the following code safer to run:

```
int
fe_shift_frame(fe_t * fe, int16 const *in, int32 len)
{
    int offset, i;

    if (len > fe->frame_shift)
        len = fe->frame_shift;
    offset = fe->frame_size - fe->frame_shift;

    /* Shift data into the raw speech buffer. */
    memmove(fe->spch, fe->spch + fe->frame_shift,
            offset * sizeof(*fe->spch));

    return 0;
}
```

source: [github](https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinxbase/blob/9e901850ee4cd1c0b22f2d3b3c15f162564ca283/src/libsphinxbase/fe/fe_sigproc.c#L852)

I want to prevent the errors of memmove, meaning; don't do the memmove when it can't be moved and will give EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS.
Something Like this: (with AreTheValuesNotOK?????)

```
int
fe_shift_frame(fe_t * fe, int16 const *in, int32 len)
{
    int offset, i;

    if (len > fe->frame_shift)
        len = fe->frame_shift;
    offset = fe->frame_size - fe->frame_shift;

    if (AreTheValuesNotOK?????)
        return -1;

    /* Shift data into the raw speech buffer. */
    memmove(fe->spch, fe->spch + fe->frame_shift,
            offset * sizeof(*fe->spch));

    return 0;
}
```

Do my lack of knowledge of C (because I normally develop with C#) I can't figure it out.
What I can understand is 'fe' is still alive when memmove() is used, because it doesn't crash before the memmove() while 'fe' is already used before that, and there are no async operations running as well.
source fe: [github](https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinxbase/blob/9e901850ee4cd1c0b22f2d3b3c15f162564ca283/src/libsphinxbase/fe/fe_internal.h#L117)

So how can I write c code to check all values going into memmove before it is invoked?

Comment: I think you have to investigate more in order to make the right fix. you say that `fe` is still alive i.e. not freed and that is ok I think. look at the arguments of `memmove()`, is `fe->spch` pointer ok? what about `offset` and `fe->spch + fe->frame_shift`? also `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` seems to be an "apple thing" I found this article which could help you [Investigating Memory Access Crashes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/investigating-memory-access-crashes)

Comment: @MarcoLucidi thanks for the reply. It's Indeed an Apple iOS thing. Currently I'm not looking for a fix but just a prevention, in a way by just checking all values. I just don't know the grammar on how to check for example if fe->spch is null or empty or if it's large enough. the memmove(XX + 20, XX+15, ....) Doesn't much sense to me as well in the memmove documentation I found. So I'm clueless on how to do simple checking :-(

Comment: a check for `NULL` is easy, e.g. `if (fe->spch != NULL) { /* do your stuff */ }`. checking for already freed memory or buffer capacity is a different story. in c we don't have "`len()`", you can't normally get the size of a buffer from just its pointer. you should find the point where the memory was allocated and with what size. if you are lucky, the size could be stored inside `fe` struct near the pointer, or maybe it's a `#define`d constant, or is somewhere else. there are tools which helps you tracking memory bugs e.g. `valgrind`, `AddressSanitizer`. a debugger (`gdb`) will also help.

Comment: @MarcoLucidi thanks for all your help. I found 'fe->frame_size' that should give some size indication because memmory has been allocated with that value. I won't bother with NULL checking because its never NULL, always some pointer value. I will just check if the offset + charachterlenght are greater the the frame_size, thats the only thing I can do.